# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, android, date, parseexception

I get the following error:
´java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Aug 31 09:53:19 2011"´ with this format: `new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");`

Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Make sure you're using the SimpleDateFormat object you created with the shown code to actually parse the given date.

Comment: Big tip: Always specify explicitly both the `Locale` and the time zone in your date-time work rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default. Both can change at any moment *during runtime*.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make sure you're using the correct locale. (The `SimpleDateFormat(String)` constructor uses  **the system default locale**, which may not be the one you want to use.)

This works fine on my machine:

```
String input = "Aug 31 09:53:19 2011";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.US);
System.out.println(df.parseObject(input));
```

(While using `Locale.FRENCH` for instance, results in a `ParseException`.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This bug was tripping me up, too.

Comment: This fixes the problem, but why? what is changed when the locale is french??

Comment: the month name - Aug would instead become août

Answer (score 7):

The format itself is OK for the input you gave. But you might get this error if your default locale is set to something where "Aug" is not a valid abbreviation of a month name. Try using for example to `Locale.US` and you'll see that it will work:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.US);
Date date = df.parse("Aug 31 09:53:19 2011");
```

Comment: I have date like this `2017-08-01T08:32:38.5544401-05:00` and this is the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz`. and i'm getting the exception. Please help

Comment: @eCDroid your date does not match the pattern; there are fractional seconds in the date string, which are not in the pattern. Use the correct pattern.

Comment: you mean ss.sssssss?

Comment: @eCDroid No, it's a bit more complicated because `SimpleDateFormat` cannot deal with 7 digits of fractional seconds. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000673/string-date-conversion-with-nanoseconds

Comment: I tried this `String actualFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSz";` and this is the result `Orignal Date: 2017-08-01T08:50:36.8762641-05:00 Converted Time: 18:50:36` Is it correct?

Comment: @eCDroid See the question I linked to.

Comment: Did you observer in my case i have seconds in decimal value no millis `08:50:36.8762641` this figure 36.8762641?

Comment: I successfully achieve it by making the pattern to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

- **Specify the [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)**, to determine human language and cultural norms used in translating the name of month.
- Use modern *java.time* classes rather that troublesome legacy classes.

Contrived example:

```
LocalDateTime.parse(                                       // Parse input text as a `LocalDateTime` lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.
    "Aug 31 09:53:19 2011" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy" )  // Specify formatting pattern to match input string.
                     .withLocale( Locale.US )              // The `Locale` determines the human language and cultural norms used in translating the input text.
)                                                          // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
```

## Details

The other two answers [by aioobe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7254363/642706) and [by Jesper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7254368/642706) are both correct: Implicitly using a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) with a human language that does not match the language of your input text.

This Answer explains a new way of doing the job. Also, the other Answers do not address the crucial issue of time zone.

## java.time

Fast forward a few years later from this posting, and we now have the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and later. These new classes supplant the old java.util.Date/.Calendar & SimpleDateFormat classes. Those old classes have proven to be troublesome, confusing, and flawed.

### Formatter Pattern

Define the data to be parsed and its format.

```
String input = "Aug 31 09:53:19 2011";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM dd HH:mm:ss uuuu" );
```

If not specified, the `DateTimeFormatter` is assigned the `Locale` that is currently the default in the JVM. That default can change at any moment, even during runtime(!). So always specify the desired/expected `Locale`.

```
formatter = formatter.withLocale( Locale.US );  // Or Locale.UK, Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, etc.
```

Given that the input lacks any time zone or offset-from-[UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) information, parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , formatter );
```

If from the context you know the intended offset-from-UTC or a time zone for this date-time value, assign it.

If UTC, use the `ZoneOffset.UTC` constant to get a `OffsetDateTime` object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

A time zone is an offset-from-UTC *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), never the [3-4 letter abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).

```
ZoneId zoneId_Montreal = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( zoneId_Montreal );
```

## Specify Time Zone

This human language element was the key missing piece to answer the Question. Specifying the correct `Locale` for the human language matching the language of your input string solves that problem.

But note that the time zone is also critical; the other answers ignored this issue thereby implicitly using the JVM’s current default time zone. That is not advisable, as it depends on the host operating system as an initial default value (so may vary) and furthermore any code in any thread of any app within the JVM can change the JVM’s current default time zone *during* runtime. Better to specify the desired/expected time zone than rely implicitly on default.

### Immutable Objects

Note the syntax. These classes are designed to be [immutable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So rather than modifying (mutating) an object, a fresh new object is created based on the old object’s values. This means we are *not* affecting the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object defined above and held in the `formatter` variable (object reference). We are creating, using, and discarding a new DateTimeFormatter object (actually, *two* new objects) within this line of code.

## Method Reference

The documentation suggests an alternative way to parse a string is to call the [`parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery-) method where you pass a [method reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) (new in Java 8) from the class of the kind of result you desire (as the [`TemporalQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalQuery.html)): `ZonedDateTime::from`, `LocalDateTime::from`, `LocalDate::from`, and so on.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = formatter.withZone( zoneId_Montreal ).withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH ).parse( input, ZonedDateTime :: from );
```

For demonstration, let's turn around and create a String representation of that `ZonedDateTime` value but in Québécois French.

```
String output = formatter.withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).format( zdt );
```

Even better, let’s localize rather than hard-code a particular format.

```
String outputLocalized = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).format( zdt );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "formatter: " + formatter );
System.out.println( "zdt: " + zdt );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
System.out.println( "outputLocalized: " + outputLocalized );
```

When run.

```
input: Aug 31 09:53:19 2011
formatter: Text(MonthOfYear,SHORT)' 'Value(DayOfMonth,2)' 'Value(HourOfDay,2)':'Value(MinuteOfHour,2)':'Value(SecondOfMinute,2)' 'Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)
zdt: 2011-08-31T09:53:19-04:00[America/Montreal]
output: août 31 09:53:19 2011
outputLocalized: mercredi 31 août 2011 9 h 53 EDT
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).