# String-Date conversion with nanoseconds 

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, datetime-format, date-parsing

I've been struggling for a while with this piece of code for an Android app and I can't get the hang of it. I've read and tried every solution I found on stackoverflow and other places, but still no luck.

What I want to do is have a function to convert a string like `"17.08.2012 05:35:19:7600000"` to a UTC date and a function that takes an `UTC date` and converts it to a string like that.

```
String value = "17.08.2012 05:35:19:7600000";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSSSSS");
try
{
  Date today = df.parse(value);
  System.out.println("Today = " + df.format(today) + " " + today.toGMTString());
} 
catch (ParseException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This results in : `Today = 17.08.2012 07:41:59:0000000 17 Aug 2012 04:41:59 GMT` which are both wrong.

I tried setting `SDF's timezone` to `UTC`, no luck.
Another thing that I noticed:   if I do `df.setLenient(false);`
It gives me : `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "17.08.2012 05:35:19:7600000"` .

If anyone can provide me with some explanations / sample code, I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The result you are getting is absolutely right.

Let's analyze this:

```
17.08.2012 05:35:19:7600000
```

- 17: Day of month (17th)
- 08: Month of year (August)
- 2012: Year (2012)
- 05: Hour of day (5am)
- 35: Minute of hour (:35)
- 19: Second of minute (:19)
- 7600000: Milliseconds of second (7,600,000)

Now, the way the VM sees this is that you are declaring the time of day as 5:35:19am, then adding 7,600,000 milliseconds to it. 7,600,000 milliseconds = 7,600 seconds = 2 hours, 6 minutes, 40 seconds. 5:35:19am + 02:06:40 = 7:41:59am (and 0 milliseconds). This is the result you are getting. (It also appears that you are not setting the timezone properly, so the GMT string is 3 hours behind your result.)

If you want to retain the `:7600000`, to my knowledge this is not possible. As this can be simplified into seconds, the VM will automatically reduce it into the other time increments. The milliseconds (the `SSSS`) should be for storing values <1000.

I'd suggest you create a new `SimpleDateFormat` for your output; but remember that the milliseconds will be absorbed into the other times (since they are all stored as a single `long` in the `Date` object).

Comment: Thank you! After setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")) all got ok. As about the milliseconds, I think I'll just reset them to 0. Don't think that it matters in my case. The example I gave was a response from a server, as a UTC now time, I'll have to see why does it return those milliseconds.

Comment: Glad you've figured out the issue! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 6):

```
    private String convertDate(String cdate)
{
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSSSSS");
    SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date convertedDate;
    try
    {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(cdate);
        cdate = postFormater.format(convertedDate);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return cdate;
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 6):

This is what you need (but it will loose millisecond information):

```
"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.'000000'"
```

If you used `"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"`, then would get three leading zeros for your milliseconds.

If you used `"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS'000'"`, then you could format a date, but not parse any date.

Try it out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    printDate("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");//02.05.2010 21:45:58.073
    printDate("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");//02.05.2010 21:45:58.000073
    printDate("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS'000'");//02.05.2010 21:45:58.073000
    printDate("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.'000000'");//02.05.2010 21:45:58.000000

    tryToParseDate("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");//good
    tryToParseDate("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");//good
    tryToParseDate("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS'000'");//bad
    tryToParseDate("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.'000000'");//good
}

private static void printDate(String formatString) {
    Date now = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
    String formattedDate = format.format(now);

    // print that date
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
}

private static void tryToParseDate(String formatString) {
    Date now = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
    String formattedDate = format.format(now);

    // try to parse it again
    try {
        format.parse(formattedDate);
        System.out.println("good");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("bad");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To drop the nanoseconds, use:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.")
```

Comment: is it possible to ignore the nanoseconds but to include the timezone in a string like this: `2020-12-15T15:40:15.000000Z`

Answer (score 0):

## Update: *java.time*

The Question and other Answers use terrible date-time classes that are now legacy. These flawed classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Avoid `Calendar`, `DateFormat`, `Date`, etc.

Define a formatting pattern with `DateTimeFormatter`.

```java
String input = "17.08.2012 05:35:19:7600000";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss:SSSSSSS" );
```

Parse.

```java
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

A `LocalDateTime` object represents a date with a time of day, but lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC.

If you are certain the input text is intended to represent a moment as seen in UTC, having an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds, then assign a `ZoneOffset` to produce an `OffsetDateTime` object.

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/darOPH).

## ISO 8601

I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the use of ISO 8601 standard formats when serializing date-time values to text.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text.