# SimpleDateFormat cannot parse milliseconds with more than 4 digits

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I want to parse a timestamp, like this - `"2016-03-16 01:14:21.6739"`. But when I use the `SimpleDateFormat` to parse it, I find that it outputs an incorrect parsed value. It will covert 6739 milliseconds to 6 seconds with 739 millseconds left. It converted the date to this format - `Wed Mar 16 01:14:27 PDT 2016`. Why the seconds part has changed from 21 seconds to 27 seconds(an addition of 6 seconds?). The following is my code snippet:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS");
String parsedate="2016-03-16 01:14:21.6739";
try {
    Date outputdate = sf.parse(parsedate);
    String newdate = outputdate.toString();  //==output date is: Wed Mar 16 01:14:27 PDT 2016 
    System.out.println(newdate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Remember that a millisecond is 0.001 of a second.  So four digit millisecond will be more than 1 sec.

Comment: yes, had changed to output the date as this code:String newdate = sf.format(outputdate); but it still output is: 2016-03-16 01:14:27.0739  ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that is not possible to use SimpleDateFormat to express times with a finer grain than the millisecond.
What is happening is that as you put 6739, Java understands it as 6739 milliseconds i.e. 6 seconds and 739 milliseconds hence the 6 seconds difference observed.

Check these ones, it is explained quite well: 
[String-Date conversion with nanoseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000673/string-date-conversion-with-nanoseconds) 
[Java date parsing with microsecond or nanosecond accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135025/java-date-parsing-with-microsecond-or-nanosecond-accuracy)

Comment: yes, it's really java version issue ,for java version less than java 8 ,we cannot use SimpleDateFormat,Date and Calendar for nanoseconds.thanks for your help .

Comment: Take to use java 8 to parse the dateTime,list the java8 code below：DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS");
  LocalDateTime newdate = LocalDateTime.parse(parsedate, dateTimeFormatter);
  System.out.println(newdate.toString());

Answer (score 5):

`SS` in [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is milliseconds. You have 6739 milliseconds, which means you are adding an extra 6.7 seconds onto your time. Perhaps you can truncate the `6739` to `673` (or if you prefer, round it to `674`) so it can be parsed correctly as milliseconds.

Comment: thanks ,currently i need to parse this String date and compare this time with current time ,i cannot cut it to SSS ,any suggestion to parse correct time "2016-03-16 01:14:21.6739"

Comment: [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) only supports millisecond precision. You _cannot_ represent `2016-03-16 01:14:21.6739` as a `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Take to use the package : java.time  pakcage in java 8 had solved my problem: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Comment: @Alter.hu, you said you are comparing the dates with the current time. For that reason you mention not to be able to strip the last digit of your dates. Just as a matter of interest: How do you obtain the current date with the 10th of a millisecond precision?

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse(
    "2016-03-16 01:14:21.6739".replace( " " , "T" )  // Comply with ISO 8601 standard format.
)
```

## Milliseconds versus Microseconds

As others noted, `java.util.Date` has millisecond resolution. That means up to 3 digits of a decimal fraction of second.

You have 4 digits in your input string, one too many. Your input value demands finer resolution such as microseconds or nanoseconds.

## java.time

Instead of using the flawed, confusing, and troublesome java.util.Date/.Calendar classes, move on to their replacement: the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

The java.time classes have a **resolution of [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond)**, up to *nine* digits of decimal fraction of a second. For example:

> 2016-03-17T05:19:24.123456789Z

### ISO 8601

Your string input is almost in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format used by default in java.time when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values. Replace that space in the middle with a `T` to comply with ISO 8601.

```
String input = "2016-03-16 01:14:21.6739".replace( " " , "T" );
```

### Unzoned

A [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is an approximation of a date-time, without any time zone context. *Not* a moment on the timeline.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
```

### UTC

Make that [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) an actual moment on the timeline by applying the intended time zone. If meant for UTC, make an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = ldt.toInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

### Zoned

If meant for a particular time zone, specify a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZoneDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( zoneId );
```

Comment: I believe that when you do

```LocalDateTime.parse( input );```

you lose time zone information (if there was any in the original string)

Comment: @ClintEastwood I think you missed the point. The input string shown in the Question has no offset-from-UTC and no time zone. So we parse an input lacking offset/zone using a class lacking offset/zone. Nothing lost. Neither the input string nor the `LocalDateTime` object represent a specific moment in time, only some possible moments over a 26-27 hour range. Reread my Answer for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to get string as final output why not use `format` instead of `parse`

```
        final SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        sf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); 
        Date curDate = new Date();

        String outputdate = sf.format(curDate);
        // 2016-03-17 09:45:28.658+0000
        System.out.println(outputdate);

        Date strToDate = new Date();
        try {
            strToDate = sf.parse(outputdate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Thu Mar 17 17:11:30 MYT 2016
        System.out.println(strToDate);
```

and instead of `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS"` use `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` check it here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"    2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
```

Comment: No, you use the timezon to parse the time ,but here the parse format had no timezoo,it will throw the exception for our code:  java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-03-16 01:14:21.6739"

Comment: @Alter.hu you can do sf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Answer (score 0):

You can use **String newdate = sf.format(outputdate);** in place of **String newdate = outputdate.toString();**

Comment: yes, it outputs to : 2016-03-16 01:14:27.0739 , but i want the time to be  "2016-03-16 01:14:21.6739" ,because it had not be 27 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above your question already contains the answer: milliseconds must not have more than 3 digits otherwise it represents at least one full second already.

That your code is working is simply due to a very questionable feature of `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, the **lenient** (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean))) option. By default a `SimpleDateFormat` has `setLenient` set to `true` wich means that the parser will try to interpret strings that do not match the pattern 100% and will convert them to date objects by means of some heuristics. For example it will accept a date `31.04.2016` and convert it to `01.05.2016`. This feature may be nice in some situations but produces questionable results in most of the cases.

If you set lenient to `false` in your code, the date string won't be parsed anymore. Making the error in the pattern more obvious:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS");
sf.setLenient(false);
String parsedate="2016-03-16 01:14:21.6739";
...
```

As `java.util.Date` is not able to represent any precision lower than milliseconds, I think the best option for you to parse your date would be to simply strip of the last digits of your input date, if the part after the dot has more than four digits. Your code might look something like this:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
sf.setLenient(false);
String parsedate="2016-03-16 01:14:21.6739";
try {
    // 23 is the length of the date pattern
    if (parsedate.length() > 23) {
        parsedate = parsedate.substring(0, 23);
    }
    Date outputdate = sf.parse(parsedate);
    String newdate = sf.format(outputdate);  //==output date is: 2016-03-16 01:14:21.673
    System.out.println(newdate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You could try to add some rounding logic as well in order to not loose all the information of the 4th digit...

Comment: yes, great tip to debug SimpleDateFormat  class ,but here i don't want to remove the last millseconds .

Comment: @Alter.hu, I don't get what my answer has to do with debugging. But if you don't want to loose the 10th of a millisecond precision you should probably use java.time classes instead. See [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)