# How to preserve milisecond data on java simpledateFormat

Tags: java, timestamp, simpledateformat, milliseconds, minute

Basically I'm trying to convert string data to Timestamp format. When I converted data to timestamp format, SimpleDateFormat added three minutes.
Because milisecond data equals 3 minute.But I want to preserve milisecond data on timestamp value.

Code:

```
public Double TimestampTest(String Timestamp ){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    Date parsedDate = null;
    try {
        parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(Timestamp);   
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
...
}
```

Timestamp value

```
2002-04-17 23:45:58.983
```

For test case

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse("2015-04-22T19:54:11.219983Z"));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse("2015-04-22 19:54:11.219983Z"));
```

Results are same for both of them

```
Wed Apr 22 19:57:50 EEST 2015

Wed Apr 22 19:57:50 EEST 2015
```

Because

```
219 983 milliseconds = 3.66638333 minutes
```

To sum up I want to preserve ms data .Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` has millisecond precision - 3 digits after decimal point. If there's more than 3 you get strange results: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36055717/7605325 - https://stackoverflow.com/q/44979279/7605325

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat cannot parse milliseconds with more than 4 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055717/simpledateformat-cannot-parse-milliseconds-with-more-than-4-digits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand, what you have at the end of your string are microseconds, not milliseconds. The old, obsolete Date and SimpleDateFormat classes have no support for microseconds. But you can use the new java.time classes:

```
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-04-22T19:54:11.219983Z",
                                       DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSVV"))));
```

Comment: I believe that in this case you can just use `parse` without a formatter - although I'm not in front of a computer to test

Comment: @Hugo is correct. If you have a requirement of exactly 6 decimals, you need a formatter, but for most uses the explicit formatter is just cluttering the code. `ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-04-22T19:54:11.219983Z")` works. Otherwise the answer is a very good one.