# Parse Micro/Nano Seconds timestamp in spark-csv Dataframe reader : Inconsistent results

Tags: apache-spark, spark-csv

I'm trying to read a csv file which has timestamps till nano seconds. 
sample content of file TestTimestamp.csv-

***spark- 2.4.0, scala - 2.11.11***

```
   /**
     * TestTimestamp.csv -
     * 101,2019-SEP-23 11.42.35.456789123 AM
     *
     */
```

Tried to read it using timestampFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS aaa"

```
val dataSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("ID", DoubleType, true), StructField("Created_TS", TimestampType, true)))

val data = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "false")
      .option("inferSchema", "false")
      .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
      //.option("nullValue", "")
      .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MMM-dd")
      .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MMM-dd hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS aaa")
      .schema(dataSchema)
      .load("C:\\TestData\\Raw\\TetraPak\\Shipments\\TestTimeStamp.csv")

    data.select('Created_TS).show
```

Output which I get is completely wrong date-time. 23rd Sept got changed to 28th September

```
+--------------------+
|          Created_TS|
+--------------------+
|2019-09-28 18:35:...|
+--------------------+
```

Even if I have Hours in 24 Hour formats like - 
"2019-SEP-23 16.42.35.456789123" 
and I try to use only first few digits of second fractions  by giving timestampFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSS"

similar incorrect result-

```
val data2 = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "false")
      .option("inferSchema", "false")
      .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
      //.option("nullValue", "")
      .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MMM-dd")
      .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MMM-dd hh.mm.ss.SSS")
      .schema(dataSchema)
      .load("C:\\TestData\\Raw\\TetraPak\\Shipments\\TestTimeStamp.csv")

    data2.select('Created_TS).show

+--------------------+
|          Created_TS|
+--------------------+
|2019-09-28 23:35:...|
+--------------------+
```

is there any way to parse such timestamp strings while **creating dataframe** using **csv reader** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution inspired by werner's answer about using udfs..-

Input csv -

```
101,2019-SEP-23 11.42.35.456789123 AM,2019-SEP-23 11.42.35.456789123 AM,2019-SEP-23 11.42.35.456789123 AM
```

Original Schema with TimestampType columns

```
val orig_schema = StructType(Array(StructField("ID", DoubleType, true), StructField("Created_TS", TimestampType, true), StructField("Updated_TS", TimestampType, true), StructField("Modified_TS", TimestampType, true)))
```

Convert all TimestampType to StringType

```
val dataSchema = StructType(orig_schema.map(x =>
      {
        x.dataType match {
          case TimestampType => StructField(x.name, StringType, x.nullable)
          case _             => x
        }

      }))
```

toDate function for convert String to Timstamp

```
//TODO parameterize string formats

    def toDate(date: String): java.sql.Timestamp = {
      val formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a").toFormatter()
      Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter))
    }

// register toDate as udf
val to_timestamp = spark.sqlContext.udf.register("to_timestamp", toDate _)
```

Create Column Expression to select from raw Dataframe

```
// Array of Column Name & Types
    val nameType: Array[(String, DataType)] = orig_schema.fields.map(f => (f.name, f.dataType))

// Create Column Expression to select from raw Dataframe
val selectExpr = nameType.map(f => {
      f._2 match {
        case TimestampType => expr(s"CASE WHEN ${f._1} is NULL THEN NULL ELSE to_timestamp(${f._1}) END AS ${f._1}")
        case _             => expr(s"${f._1}")
      }
    })
```

Read as StringType , Use column selector expression which uses udf to convert string to Timestamp

```
val data = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "false")
      .option("inferSchema", "false")
      .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
      //.option("nullValue", "")
      .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MMM-dd")
      .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MMM-dd hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS aaa")
      .schema(dataSchema)
.load("C:\\TestData\\Raw\\TetraPak\\Shipments\\TestTimestamp_new.csv").select(selectExpr: _*)

data.show
```

Here's desired output..so now I don't have to worry about number of columns and creating expressions with udf manually

```
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|   ID|          Created_TS|          Updated_TS|         Modified_TS|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|101.0|2019-09-23 11:42:...|2019-09-23 11:42:...|2019-09-23 11:42:...|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

The [DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html) uses the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for parsing dates:

> timestampFormat (default yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX): sets the string that indicates a timestamp format. Custom date formats follow the formats at java.text.SimpleDateFormat. This applies to timestamp type.

Unfortunately, the SimpleDateFormat does not support nano seconds, so the part of your dates after the last dot will be interpreted as 456789123 milliseconds, which is approx 126 hours. This time is added to your date, this explains the strange results that you see. More details on this topic can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12000749/2129801).

So the dates have to be parsed in a second step after reading the csv, for example with a udf that uses a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```scala
val dataSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("ID", DoubleType, true), StructField("Created_TS_String", StringType, true)))

var df = spark.read.option("header", false)
  .option("inferSchema", "false")
  .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
  .schema(dataSchema)
  .csv("C:\\TestData\\Raw\\TetraPak\\Shipments\\TestTimeStamp.csv")

val toDate = udf((date: String) => {
  val formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a").toFormatter()
  Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter))
})

df = df.withColumn("Created_TS", toDate('Created_TS_String))
```

Comment: Thanks, you're correct.. UDF seems to be the only way. I've around 280 total columns in input file.. I'll have to identify all timestamps and map column array to expressions which uses toDate udf and then select from df (which read all ts columns as string)