# How to pass Session parameters to Oracle in azure datafactory copy activity.. In Oracle Linkedservice

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm copying data from an Oracle instance in aws, self hosted integration runtime service running on a VM in source network.

Issue is, while copying data from Oracle database using copy data activity in Azure, how do I pass session parameters like - NLS_DATE_FORMAT, NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT to oracle session to make timestamp strings in certain format.

Copy activity sink is csv. Files written in csv format with timestamp precision till nanoseconds isn't parseable by spark's csv-reader.

Hence It seemed best idea to bring only seconds to azure from oracle by settings NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT parameter to YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS

Please suggest how to do it?

My another question on this topic here -[Parse Micro/Nano Seconds timestamp in spark-csv Dataframe reader : Inconsistent results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557480/parse-micro-nano-seconds-timestamp-in-spark-csv-dataframe-reader-inconsistent)

providing it under connection properties parameters availed in no help. See attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the parameters (NLS_DATE_FORMAT etc) as System properties in the VM that is hosting the Self Hosted Ingration Runtime.