# Converting date.toString() to date

Tags: java, date, exception

I'm trying to convert a string to a date. I've got an example here with the input string as hardcoded string.

```
try {
    String currentDate = "Tue Jan 05 21:19:57 CET 2016";
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US).parse(currentDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For some reason, this throws the following exception:

```
ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jan 05 21:19:57 CET 2016" (at offset 20)
```

Could someone help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: *"this throws the following exception"* ... well, not for me. Have copy pasted this code snippet?

Comment: please change the current local and try to run this code again to make sure that issue related to local, tired with different local  but not US and I have the same exception

Comment: Small addition to @AhmadAl-Kurdi's comment, CET is Central European Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is described her [java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254307/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date)

Your machine Local can effect the local that used in SimpleDateFormat