# Exception on Date parsing android

Tags: android, android-activity, simpledateformat, date-parsing, android-date

I am using a function to take out the difference between a given date and current date. At all the places, that function is working just fine but at one place, it is throwing the `unparseable date` exception.

Below is the function that I use:

```
public boolean timeDiff24hrs(String alarmTime) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date date = new Date();
    String s = sdf.format(date);
    String alarmDateStr="";
    try {
        Date alarmDate=sdf.parse(alarmTime);
        alarmDateStr=sdf.format(alarmDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int diff = diffOf2Days(alarmDateStr, s);

    if (diff > 1439) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here I get the exception trying to execute the `try` block.

The `alarmDate` that I pass into the function is :
`1/31/2018 8:58:12 AM +00:00`

Can someone please explain.

Comment: For date "1/31/2018 8:58:12 AM +00:0" your date formate is not correct .

Comment: that date is not for the format you are using

Comment: `unparseable` comes when passing date is not valid format.

Comment: Change Your Date Format To Appropriate Format

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: If you based your code off some tutorial, you either found a very poor tutorial (they exist) or didn’t read it well enough. Try a couple of others (and I repeat: try one that uses `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` from `java.time`).

Comment: I recommend `OffsetDateTime.parse("1/31/2018 8:58:12 AM +00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu h:mm:ss a xxx", Locale.ENGLISH))`.

Comment: This question is *not* an exact duplicate of [java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254307/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date). In that question the locale was the problem. In this question the problem is that the format pattern string and the alarm date string don’t match when it comes to the `T` and what follows. Very many questions have been asked about unparseable date exception from `SimpleDateFormat`, and searching those is a good idea (also before posting a new question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date format `MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss` which your using is incorrect `1/31/2018 8:58:12 AM +00:00` and return different value from expected.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

> return     1/31/2018T8:58:12

And you are trying to pass below

```
1/31/2018 8:58:12 AM +00:00
```

Comment: A very direct answer to “Can someone please explain.” :-)